# ¿Como sanear los datos de un array en php?

Tags: php

¿De que forma puedo sanear los datos que tiene un array antes de ser enviado para ser guardado en una base de datos?
mi array es el siguiente.

```
#este es mi controlador
public function GuardarDatosController()
{
    if (isset($_POST["guardar"]))
    {
        $Data = array(
            "nombre" => $_POST["txtNombre"],
            "cantidad" => $_POST["txtcantidad"],
            "precio" => $_POST["txtprecio"],
            "email" => $_POST["txtemail"]
        );
        $reply = CRUDModel::GuardarDatosModel($Data, "productos");
        if ($reply == "ok") {
            echo "se ingresaron los datos";
        }else{
            echo $reply;
        }
    }
}


#este es mi modelo
public function GuardarDatosModel($Values,$Table)
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO $Table ";
        $query.="(".implode(" , ",array_keys($Values)).")" ;
        $query.=" VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($Values))."');";
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($query);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }
        else{
            return "error";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

He pensado en utilizar algún preg-match o algun Filter de PHP, pero me gustaría saber cual puede ser una buena solución para este caso, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: busca informacion sobre inyeccion sql en el sitio... esa es la forma de sanear tu array...

Comment: Hola. Creo que debes leer esto para manejar sentencias preparadas en php. Hasta la fecha es el mejor manual que he leído: [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: Lo más simple y más seguro es usar consultas preparadas y si vas a pasar tablas en variables tener una lista blanca de tablas con las que comparar la variable `$Table`. Si usas PDO lee atentamente el enlace que te sugiere @quevedo, es lo mejor que he visto. Gracias a ese tutorial aprendí a usar PDO de la forma más segura y eficaz.